# Custom type-dependent template loader

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As you might know, ASP.NET MVC has support for custom view overrides for model fields within views. There are special folders in the `Views` folder called `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates`, `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates` and so on, and these folders can contain files like `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\String.cshtml`, which will override the default view used when calling `@Html.EditorFor` in a view with a model with a `String` field.

What I want to do is to use this functionality for a custom kind of templates. I want to have a folder like `Views\Shared\GroupTemplates` that may contain e.g. `Views\Shared\GroupTemplates\String.cshtml` and `Views\Shared\GroupTemplates\Object.cshtml`, and I want to create a `HtmlHelper` method that allows me to call for example `Html.GroupFor(foo => foo.Bar)`, which will load the template in `String.cshtml` if `Bar` is a `String` property, and the template in `Object.cshtml` otherwise.

---

Full example of the expected behavior; if `Views\Shared\GroupTemplates\String.cshtml` contains this:

```
@model String
This is the string template
```

... and `Views\Shared\GroupTemplates\Object.cshtml` contains this:

```
@model Object
This is the object template
```

I have a model like:

```
class Foo
{
    public bool Bar { get; set; }
    public String Baz { get; set; }
}
```

And a view in `Views\Foo\Create.cshtml` like:

```
@model Foo
@Html.GroupFor(m => m.Bar)
@Html.GroupFor(m => m.Baz)
```

When I render the view `Create.cshtml`, the result should be this:

```
This is the object template
This is the string template
```

How should `GroupFor` be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you can easily specify your view location like that

```
html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/GroupTemplates/YourViewName.cshtml");
```

or even override default behaviour by implementing custom view engine, for an example see this blog [A Custom View Engine with Dynamic View Location](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx)

But you also want to reuse the logic which determines the view name based on its model type. So that if a view with String name doesn't exist an Object view is picked up. Which means going through parent classes.

I've had a look how EditorFor is implemented:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    return html.TemplateFor<TModel, TValue>(expression, null, null, DataBoundControlMode.Edit, null);
}
```

It uses TemplateFor method which is internal and you can't just reuse it.

So I can only see of two options:

1. Implement you custom logic by checking if a view file with a correct name exists by trying model type name and its parent classes. And if you find a proper view just use Partial extension in your helper.
2. Try to use reflection to call internal method. But this approach is more like a hack than a solution.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I looked at [the source code for ASP.NET MVC](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com) and simply copied the type chain generation algorithm from there. This is basically what you said, so I'll accept your answer.